# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable read would block

Tags: ruby, heroku, intuit-partner-platform

Currently seeing this error from our background workers on Heroku when posting text/plain queries to the Intuit v3 API. https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123456789/query/

Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.0.10

OAuth 0.4.5 https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby

There is an error_message "Intuit's API timed out. They may be over capacity. Please try again later". I'm not sure if this is just an intermittent error that we should ignore, or if it's an issue on the Intuit side or with Ruby/OpenSSL on Heroku?

This error isn't happening a lot, but we have one customer who reports being unable to sync for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku timeouts are 30s. Intuit's api may be taking longer possibly. I suggest you try from a local machine or try to test from AWS if you are familiar or another cloud provider. Another thing you could do is test running the api on the command line from heroku console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this is the issue because we are running in background workers. As far as I can tell, Heroku doesn't have a 30 second timeout for background worker dynos.

Comment: Yeah, we are seeing this now too - and yeah, there is no timeout in background workers..